# Searching for a ReactJS Runtime Plugin Concept

Tags: javascript, reactjs

does ReactJS support some plugin loading at runtime?
I have developed a client app based on ReactJS. It should be possible for other users of my software to extend the Web UI by writing custom extension.

My ReactJS Base application is already transpiled (webpack + babel) to a build.js file.

Other user should create there own .js file which are loaded by the browser separately. At runtime browser should check for custom extension add these to the application.

Does anyone has a hint how to do this with ReactJS?

Cheers,
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom javascript function on your main component to add extensions, i.e.:

```
YourPlugin.loadExtensions(MyCustomExtension);
```

I've done this for a react component to be mount on a specific node only, but I think this approach should work in your case as well.

Comment: Hi Pedro,

thanks for the quick response. Can you provide me some more lines of the example. 

Is loadExtension() a custom function I have to code on my own?

Comment: Yes, it is. You'd maybe add something to your react app to check in the global state, or have your app mounted using ReactDOM and making sure you hook these extensions through props using ReactDOM itself. I recommend the latter.

Comment: I'm still searching for an answer. I found webpack chunking but this is running at the transpile time. 

I really like to have separate js-files

index.js
plugin1.js
plugin2.js